# Forbidden relationships between subordinates and managers -- is it possible or impossible to handle it without banning it?

Tags: ethics, relationships

While drafting the workplace rules of a small business, I got to the part where I have to decide what to do with workplace romance, and I'm indecisive as to what to do with romantic relationships between a manager and a subordinate. A previous job I once held had a strict policy of forbidding that kind of romance and making it a valid reason for termination from the company, and seeing other posts in this site on that matter, I would believe the best way to proceed would be indeed by forbidding these relationships.

However... I don't know what happens elsewhere, but at least in my country, forbidden romance is considered to be the most passionate and exciting kind. So if I were to prohibit romantic relationships between a manager and a subordinate, and an employee falls in love with his manager, this will result in a forbidden love that will cause terrible tensions in the workplace as both parties try as hard as possible to keep it on the down low but subconsciously let it slip into the workplace every now and then. And coming the day said relationship ends up falling apart, this failed affair will translate into visible and seemingly gratuitous tensions between the manager and the subordinate. And at the same time, I wouldn't like to have to fire a valuable employee or a competent manager just because their heart decided to aim for the wrong person.

With that in mind, is it possible to allow romantic relationships between managers and subordinates? A policy that comes into my mind is having the couple disclose their relationship to the management and putting a closer watch on the decisions and moves of these two employees in order to prevent their relationship from contaminating the workplace as much as possible.

Comment: As you've read all over the place, don't go that road. This creates toxic environments and if you don't give yourself the tools to get rid of trouble people from the get go, it will be hard to change the rules later.

Comment: "is it possible to allow romantic relationships..." - Another option you may be overlooking is to just have your policy be silent on such issues. And include a catch-all in your policy somewhere that allows you to consider disciplinary actions for things not covered by the policy but that turn out to be a negative influence on the work environment. Or something to that effect.

Comment: You could try banning it, but a more pragmatic approach could be the requirement of complete disclosure, a release of liability if the relationship goes sour, coupled with a transfer of responsibility when it comes to raises, signing time sheets, promotions, hirings, and firings. At the very least, you should forbid the hiring of any family member, or lovers (because that's an easier policy to implement if the person wasn't hired already). And you should definitely forbid two lovers from working in financial accounting together, to avoid one covering for the other when it comes to errors/fraud

Comment: In any case, you should really consult a lawyer in your jurisdiction, or at least consult a book that gives you legal guidance on this issue. This is not something that you should make up on the cuff. There are usually very specific legal reasons for these kinds of policies.

Comment: Depends if this is a movie or real life

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Think what he is getting at is by the company forbidding it, they're actually encouraging it.

Answer (score 9):

> I would believe the best way to proceed would be indeed by forbidding
>   these relationships.

Why? They're certainly not advisable, and conflict of interest is almost inevitable, but if you're in a small business, making detailed rules like that on what employees can and cannot do in their free time is a waste of time.

As you properly pointed out, explicitly forbidding something for comparatively little reason is going to make it more enticing.

I suggest you don't explicitly forbid this, but instead deal with it on a case-by-case basis. Some of these relationships can be no problem at all. An example would be a member of the Janitorial Staff dating an Office worker.

Big Corporations often do these Boilerplate "No employee relationships allowed period" rules to avoid having to properly deal with the individual cases, but you shouldn't do that when starting a small business.

Comment: This. I have personally several workplace romances, and I am not aware of any problems they caused. Of course they can cause problems, but so can many other things, such as rivalries or personal conflicts - just deal with the problem when it manifests itself. If people misbehave, it does not really matter whether they do it because of a failed relationship or because the don't like someone's nose.

Answer (score 2):

You are their employer not their relationship councillor: as such, your duty is to their productivity, efficiency and not breaking any workplace laws about bullying etc.

Therefore, it is far simpler and cleaner for the business to simply say that any type of romantic relationship between employees (not just supervisor/supervisee) are off-limits.  If they want a relationship then everything is easy: one of them has to resign.

**The purpose of the policy is to protect the employer - not to make people happy.** Except indirectly, a small employer who goes bankrupt due to being sued for workplace harassment will make a lot of people unhappy.

Of course, we all know that this type of thing will go on clandestinely, however, the policy has changed this from being a workplace harassment problem for the employer to being a misconduct problem for the employees.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I've never ever seen this kind of thing in a workplace rules policy. While I can see the practical reason for requiring it, I think it's best left alone, and instead have strict rules about workplace bullying,  favouritism, sexual harassment (include public displays of affection on company property) and that kind of thing. i.e. the practical stuff.

Perhaps when it came to employee evaluation, a manager would have to disclose anything that might lead to a conflict of interest which this would include.

For a start, I very think it would be very difficult to enforce.

Employees have the right to do what they want in their own time, and you're kind of trying to take control of their personal lives. But what are you going to do if you find out they are meeting up every night? How would you make them stop? Threaten disciplinary action? Start asking them about their sex lives?

Will you stop them meeting up as friends too? That could have similar consequences (favouritism, negative feeling after a falling out).

I would think it better to trust the professionalism of your employees. And hire employees whose professionalism you can trust.

Also, I wouldn't even sure it would be legal to have such a stipulation.